# Blogger API - Get URL After Create Post

Tags: php, api, google-api, blogger

I am creating a post on my blogger blog using the blogger API.

This is based on the sample code here:

http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/Gdata/Blogger.php

I can successfully create a post and I get the postid returned.

I was wondering how I can get the URL (permalink, or non permalink) of the newly created post from the returned postid?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Same issue, any luck? I can see the URL in the returned response but I can't figure out how to extract the URL from the object. I'm pretty sure I could turn the object into a string (var_dump/var_export) and extract the URL from the string but I assume there is a method for getting the URL directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just after I posted my comment I found the solution.

The `$createdPost` variable in the example will have a method named `getAlternateLink`. Use it like this:

```
$altLink = $createdPost->getAlternateLink();
$url = $altLink->getHref();
```

What I did to find this was a simple loop:

```
foreach (get_class_methods($createdPost) AS $method) {
  echo '<br>' . $method;
  try {
    if (strpos($method, 'get') !== FALSE) { echo ': '; var_dump($createdPost->$method()); }
  } catch (Exception $e) {

  }
}
```

This will echo out the result of each method that contains get in it. There are lots of set methods but that isn't what you need here. There are other get methods that will give you the link to edit, comment